# How should I add a series of questions to my Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails app where there are Sales Opportunities. Each opportunity is graded by the User according to where they believe it belongs in the sales pipeline. This is set up as an enum currently on the Sales Opportunity model, and the user just selects the appropriate stage from a dropdown list. The stages are "Prospecting", "Qualifying", "Demonstrating", "Negotiating", "Closed Won", "Closed Lost" and "Dormant".

I am now looking to build more sophisticated features for a premium part of the product - specifically I want to be able to add questions to the Sales Opportunity that the user answers - e.g. "Does the prospect have a budget?", if yes: "How much is their budget?" etc.

Depending upon the answers to these questions I want to display a result to the user telling them where in the sales pipeline this opportunity *should* belong, rather than where it currently is.

I was thinking of adding a qualifying_questions class relationship to Sales_Opportunity.rb:

```
class SalesOpportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 enum pipeline_status: [ :prospect, :qualifying, :demonstrating, :negotiating, :closed_won, :closed_lost, :dormant ]
 has_many :qualifying_questions
end
```

and then creating QualifyingQuestions class:

```
class QualifyingQuestions < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :sales_opportunity
end
```

But this is where I'm getting stuck in my mind. Each question is likely to have different characteristics - e.g. in my example above the first questions's answer is a boolean (do they have budget?) whereas the next (assuming the answer was yes) is either a fixnum ($20,000 for example) or a selector saying "unknown", or if they don't have a budget (answer no to the first question) I want to ask "is there a process to allocate budget?" etc.

I could create a class for each individual question I ask, and set the data types accordingly - but this seems to be massively bloating the code, and it means my questions need to be hard-coded into the app. Ideally in future I'd like to allow my Users to define their own questions for each stage in the sales process, so I should try and design it to be flexible for the future.

I'm sure there's a straightforward way for me to achieve this, but I'm not sufficiently experienced to know it yet. Can anyone help point me in the right direction please?

Comment: This answer isn't necessarily specific to coding in RoR, but essentially what you need to generally develop is 1) a way of creating question ontologies (or a question tree) and 2) a way to parse those ontologies. It's hard for someone to give you real advice since I don't have a great grasp of your problem just from reading this short blurb about what you're doing. I don't know what all those things are either.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'll start googling question ontonlogies/question trees and parsing - I'm sure there's someone with a similar problem that I could learn from, I just didn't really know what to search for. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: I think your best approach would be the creation of a Service Class to handle this. It seems like something that does require an ActiveRecord model of it's own, but needs to be encapsulated within it's own class. Perhaps named ```class SalesStageRecommender``` following convention to name services as actions/verbs.

Comment: Thanks Ben. So the class SalesStageRecommender would just receive answers to the questions and decide which stage it belongs in, then pass that back to the view for the SalesOpportunity? I was thinking of using the Wicked gem to act as a controller to jump between questions, but that would still require that I hard-code my questions (and the path between them) rather than let someone configure their own (e.g. in a SurveyMonkey type build your own question/answer path).

Comment: How would a question determine the "position" of the opportunity?

Comment: The questions would belong_to a stage in the pipeline - so you might have to answer 5 questions to justify the opportunity as "Qualified" before another 5 questions appear to determine if you've completed "Demonstrating" the features to move into the next category. More likely I'd use the answers to each question to determine whether to move the opportunity into the next category or not, but that's a little more complex and possibly overkill for my first attempt at solving this.